# First row with two items second one and next with three

Tags: django, loops, templates, frontend

I have model (Event) and I want to have template with two ways to display items.
First row have to include two items, with special styling
Second one and next have to include three,  with special styling

How can I do this with loop?

Answer (score 0):

you can do like below

views.py

```
def view(request):
  events = Event.objects.all()
  l = []
  for i in range(0,len(events), 5):
      l.append((events[i:i+2], events[i+2:i+5]))
  return render(request, "template.html", {"events": l})
```

template.html

```
{% for two_items, three_items in events %}
   <tr class="class1">
   {% for item in two_items %}
    <td> {{ item }}</td>
   {% endfor %}
   <tr>
   <tr class="class2">
   {% for item in three_items %}
    <td> {{ item }}</td>
   {% endfor %}
   <tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Combination of [cycle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle) and [forloop](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#for) tags will give you desired output:
For example:

```
{% for item in items %}
    {% if forloop.counter < 3 %}
        {% if forloop.first %}
            <tr class="A">
        {% endif %}
        <td>{{ item }}</td>
    {% endif %}
    {% if forloop.counter == 3 %}
        </tr>
    {% endif %}
    {% if forloop.counter >= 3 %}
        {% cycle "<tr class='B'>" "" "" %}
        <td>{{ item }}</td>
        {% cycle "" "" "</tr>" %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```